# Invoking WinRT GestureRecognizer from a desktop app in Windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime, desktop

GestureRecognizer is in the list of APIs that can be invoked from a Desktop app in win8.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh920511%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The problem is that to invoke ProcessDownEvent I need to pass a PointerPoint. And I can only get one from a CoreWindow object... and there I am stuck, since obviously, not being a "Metro" app, CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread() returns null.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent for GestureRecognizer on Desktop is InteractionContext, you don't need to deal with DirectManipulation.

There isn't much documentation on it but here is a code sample: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/comparing-touch-coding-techniques-windows-8-desktop-touch-sample

Comment: Thank you. My question was not completely accurate, since I was referring to managed desktop apps. I've tried using WPF for my purposes, but I couldn't workaround a random lag... I will look at the link.

Answer (score 0):

PointerPoint seems to have static methods to get information of certain pointers, one of such methods is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242063

Comment: The problem is that the pointer Id is only available through a CoreWindow invocation. I.E. you need to subscribe to CoreWindow::PointerPressed event and get the pointer Id via args.CurrentPoint.PointerId. I've tried 0 or 1 and it doesn't work (not that I would hard code those values)

Answer (score 0):

And apparently that is not possible, as per combining this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/e65f53b4-cac9-44e3-aa10-cd7955d6a9b3

with this: Minimum supported client Windows 8 [Windows Store apps only] 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer.aspx

Too bad the GestureRecognizer is tied so tightly to Metro apps. It's basically just math.

The options are legacy APIs or DirectManipulation which is extremely badly documented. Kinda says it all for a company betting everything on 'touch'.